# Get only http status code with sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, http

I have to check the http status codes of some domains, with the smallest amount of traffic is possible.

I decided to use sockets. Problem is that the system is receiving allways the full header and not only 20 byte.

How can i reduce the response more?

Here is the code...works fine

```
    string uri = "www.stackoverflow.com";
    var addresses = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(uri);
    IPEndPoint hostep = new IPEndPoint(addresses[0], 80);
    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sock.Connect(hostep);
    if (sock.Connected)
    {
        byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+uri+"\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n");
        int i = sock.Send(msg,0,msg.Length);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
        i = sock.Receive(bytes);
        string header = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(header);
    }
```

Thanks for each small help!

Comment: Why do you need to reduce the size of the responses?  I'm not convinced you'd get any speed benefit by receiving tens rather than hundreds of bytes (both will likely fit into a single tcp frame).

Comment: its about the amount of domains. I have to check some million status codes. When the Header has ~ 400-500 Bytes the download traffic for 10 million domains is ~ 4,6 GByte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = sock.Receive(bytes, 20);
```

However, that's pointless: the computer most likely has already received the TCP-packet with the full response, and all you do is just read only a part of the sytem buffer.

Comment: Yes i was thinking about that. Can i force him to dont donwload the whole TCP-packet? Or do i have to live with that?

Comment: Even if you could, it wouldn't matter: the Internet provider's hardware would relay the whole TCP-packet and record its size.